# Adding network printer in Kubuntu 11.04 with printer account?

Tags: 11.04, networking, kubuntu, printing

I just migrated from Ubuntu 10.10 to Kubuntu 11.04 and ran into some trouble when I tried adding the office printer to the new installation.

The printer is a Konica Minolta bizhub c253 network printer which requires an account number (account track in Windows) when printing.

What I have tried is the following:

1. Gone into System settings->Printer configurations, chosen New Printer
2. Tried adding the printer as LPD, socket and ipp (I was given an IP-adress to the printer, and an account number)
3. Supplied the ppd file downloaded from Konica Minolta and finished adding the printer

All this works, I have not been able to find any way to add the account number to the printer options though. This used to be possible to set below the Finishing options in the Printer options tab. Any suggestions? Am I adding the printer as the wrong type of printer, or why are there no account options below the Finishing options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending ages trying different drivers from Konica Minoltas homepage, I finally found the same old driver I used in 10.04/10.10, which is called "KMACPS driver for C203-C253-C353". Account track does not seem to be available in the newer drivers for some reason.